# .Net Core with Angular Authorization does not return 401

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am building a .net core 5 app with angular front end. I have implemented a controller action which works fine. I am now adding a windows based authentication and a authorize attribute to the controller action.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TransformerMeterDataController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<TransformerMeterDataController> _logger;
    private readonly DevicesDataHandler _dataHandler;
    private readonly AppSettings _config;

    public TransformerMeterDataController(ILogger<TransformerMeterDataController> logger, DevicesDataHandler dataHandler, IOptions<AppSettings> config)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _dataHandler = dataHandler;
        _config = config.Value;
    }
    [HttpGet("searchdevices")]
    //[Authorize(Policy = "MeterDataOnly")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SearchDevices(string prefix)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Getting devices started");
    }
}
```

when I hit the following url -
`https://website/api/TransformerMeterData/searchdevices?prefix=sp`
it should return 401/403 because current user is not authorized but it redirects me to the / page and status code in the console is 200.

my startup class is

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        
        //services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection(AppSettings.SettingsName));
        services.AddSingleton<DevicesCacheHandler>();
        services.AddSingleton<DevicesDataHandler>();
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
                "MeterDataOnly", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new MeterDataGroupRequirement("GroupName")));
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MeterDataGroupHandler>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        //services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, DevicesDataHandler dataHandler)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddFile(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        
        
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }
        
        
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseRouting();
        
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });

        _ = dataHandler.EnsureDevicesAsync();
    }
```

this is the response in console

[image]

If I remove the authorize attribute, everything works fine.

Comment: not sure what happened to the images.

Comment: paste formatted code instead of images

Comment: Hi @Ali - please read this first: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: images removed and code added.

Comment: much better. Now - does authentication alone work? remove authorization, and try again

Comment: yes, windows authentication works fine. Removing authorization also works fine. Problem happens when I add Authorization attribute and it current user is not authorized. It should should 401 or 403 in browser console but it redirects me to / page and status is 200.

Answer (score 0):

> it should return 401/403 because current user is not authorized but it redirects me to the / page and status code in the console is 200.

You **did not add authentication services** by **invoking AddAuthentication** in the code you provided in **Startup.ConfigureServices**.

You commented it out.

- `//services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`

You can **[click this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)** to see how to configure Windows authentication in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Adding authentication back. same result.